# Should I redirect if user tries to access a page which requires authentication?

Tags: rest

For my `404` page the url in the addressbar is persists.

This enables the user to possible fix a typo in the url.

What should I display in the addressbar when a user tries to access a page which requires authentication while the user isn't logged in?

The url of the page the user wanted to visit, e.g.:

```
http://example.com/authenticated-page
```

Or the url of the authentication required url

```
http://example.com/login
```

Comment: You can always store the requested url in the session and pull it up back up on the login page for the user to cut/paste if they want to fix things... and redirect back to that page upon successful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is common practice. Some prefer to have a dialog notification first. Your choice.

Comment: The question is option `a` or option `b` and you answer with `Yes` :P

Comment: Duh :) Redirect to the login page.